# TypeScript modules referencing

Tags: inheritance, module, compiler-errors, typescript

Have a look at the following TypeScript code:

```
module events {
    export class Event {
    }
}

module display.events {
    export class DisplayEvent extends events.Event {
    }
}
```

Basically, the idea is that `DisplayEvent` class from the module `display.events` is a descendant of `Event` class from the module `events`. There is however a problem with a naming of the modules thus the compiler searches for the `Event` class is `display.events` module:

```
error TS2094: The property 'Event' does not exist on value of type 'events'.
```

Is here any way to make the compiler (version 0.9.1.1) understand the structure of the modules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't currently a way to do this without restructuring the names of the objects. It's basically a runtime problem -- the variables are lexically scoped and 'events' has been shadowed.

Answer (score 1):

Why not change your code to look like this (which works)?

```
module display.events {
    export class Event {
    }
}

module display.events {
    export class DisplayEvent extends events.Event {
    }
}
```

Comment: Because my general `Event` class doesn't belong to `display` module. It belongs to `events` module. As Ryan said it's a runtime problem and as I can see in the resulting javascript code the name 'events' has been shadowed in the `display` module.